# Dispatch Planning in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am new to excel and have learned a lot from this portal. I am stuck at a point and I don't know how to approach the problem. I have close to zero knowledge of excel macros. I am looking for a formula based solution if possible. I would be very thankful to anyone who could help me out here.

**Problem:**

I have to plan dispatch of finished goods. I have 4 different Mother Godowns, each stores products. I have different products each with its own product code. And I have supply depots which are temporary storage stations fed by mother godowns.

I have the cost matrix of moving goods from each mother godown to each supply depot.

My task is to plan dispatch of my goods from my mother godowns to my supply depots with minimum cost.

**--NOTE--: A single mother godown may not be sufficient to meet the requirements of a particular supply depot. In that case the goods will be dispatched from more than one mother godown to the same supply depot..**

**--NOTE--: Route Formation is not required. All the different trucks will be moving from one Mother Godown to one supply depot at a time only. I just need to identify how to allocate the dispatch quantity.**

**Please refer attached images for better understanding of the question**

[Data File with inputs and output required](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8QxL2.jpg)

[Cost Matrix for goods movement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/41HYP.jpg)

Comment: Yeah I did run a simplex solver on this. And it worked.

Comment: But now a new problem has surfaced, I have a model for minimizing one instance, i.e. dispatch plan for one product will be created, i.e., the first 11 rows of the output format (see the image DATA File) will be filled. But I have multiple products. So how to automate the process to make it run for all the products (Rows) one after the other?